# Disqus Javascript API crossdomain issue on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, disqus

I'm trying to build a page that shows links to a bunch of my blog posts, and a little bubble next to each link with the comment count for that post. Thought the easiest way to do this would be to use the "Javascript public facing API" that disqus talks about in their dev docs.

If I visit this link in the browser I get the JSON I am looking for:

https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/details.json?forum=BLOG_FORUM&thread:ident=BLOG_THREAD&api_key=PUBLIC_API_KEY

However when I try to load it from jQuery it gives me the dreaded XMLHttpRequest cannot load: Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I have tried using $.getJSON() and $("#div").load() to load it.

I have added both localhost and 127.0.0.1 to the "Domains linked to my public key" settings in Disqus API.

Comment: I can't find the "Javascript public facing API" you're referring to.  There are a few things on their [JavaScript page](http://docs.disqus.com/developers/js/), but none sound like that.

Comment: They talk about it here in the first sentence: http://disqus.com/api/docs/requests/ but they don't explain much further :(

Comment: The problem is that you need to do a JSONP request.  The de facto standard for this is a callback parameter.  With `jQuery.getJSON`, you can just add `&callback=?` and jQuery will take it from there.  I still think `count.js` is easier for this particular scenario.

Comment: If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it. Additionally, I had to make sure the request was to details.jsonp instead of details.json. While count.js is great unfortunately I need to be able to customize my display of the count

Comment: I've added another answer.  However, I think you can also configure Disqus to just show the raw number with count.js, then style it as you want.

Comment: hmm, thx! Not sure which answer to approve now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use [this API](http://disqus.com/api/docs/requests/) client-side, you need to do a JSONP request. The de facto standard for this is a callback parameter specifying the function name.  Disqus also requires changing `.json` to `.jsonp`  With `jQuery.getJSON`, you can then just add `&callback=?` and jQuery will take it from there.

Comment: I've always bad request, i don't understand way.
I use Mootools -> Request.JSONP({..}).send();
As url : "https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/list.jsonp?api_key=9ldXlWCWlsyjMI3qvf03Y8OQCNxvAMklHkrNVcpBKm220XJHXsU0QDdr0TCLM1kz&callback=?"

Can you help me???

Answer (score 3):

You cant add **"localhost"** as a Origin entry in Response header. This is because of the JavaScript Security Specification for **CORS**

**Access-Control-Allow-Origin** can be set to ***** to allow any website to access the data through XMLHTTPRequest/AJAX But you can't set it to **"localhost"** though.

Possible solution to overcome the issue are:
To host the page that makes the request in a public domain/location and include the host name in the response header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**.

as "@Matthew Flaschen" mentioned, you can use JSONP request with `&callback=?` to accomplish this

Or as a last resort, load the JSON result along with a script in a `<script>` tag by specifying the URL in "src" attribute and access the JSON data
eg: modify the result in the server-side to include a `<variable_name>={JSONObject}` technique and as the script loads, the data is accessible through that variable

Some People got the same kind of issue [here](http://meteatamel.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/access-control-allow-origin/)


Still couldn't figure out why browsers deny `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=localhost` but they support `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*` (means that any public websites can access the data but..........) There might be some conspiracy in this thing (track websites that access the data)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do this by just using a script and data-driven attributes, by following [these instructions](http://docs.disqus.com/developers/universal/#comment-count).  You just load the Disqus count.js script, then use `data-` attributes.

EDIT: You can configure it to just show the integer [here](http://docs.disqus.com/help/3/) (then you can style as you wish around that).

Comment: This looks promising Matthew, thanks, will try in a little bit and let you know how it works out

Comment: This is not possible with Single Page Applications.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need this header at the top:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://disqus.com'); ?>
```

Comment: you can't add a header to a site that isn't providing it.